# JavaSwing GriBagLayout Placeing Problems

Tags: java, swing

I had tried many ways to put the components on top of the panel, but they kept standing in the middle of the panel.

```
private void setWestPanel() {
        westPanel = new JPanel();
        westPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        westPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        westPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        JPanel westSubPanel = new JPanel();

        solveBtn = new JButton("Giải");
        resetBtn = new JButton("Xóa");
        exitBtn = new JButton("Thoát");

        solveBtn.setFocusable(false);
        resetBtn.setFocusable(false);
        exitBtn.setFocusable(false);

        solveBtn.setMnemonic('G');
        resetBtn.setMnemonic('X');
        exitBtn.setMnemonic('T');

        solveBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resetBtn.addActionListener(this);
        exitBtn.addActionListener(this);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        westPanel.add(solveBtn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        westPanel.add(resetBtn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        westPanel.add(exitBtn, gbc);

        add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }
```

I want components to stand in the middle of the panel. I had tried gbc.anchor, but it didn't work.

Current:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocOEp.png]

What I expecting:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD2ON.png]

Comment: Have you considered using [MigLayout](https://www.miglayout.com/) instead of `GridBagLayout`? It's much simpler to maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... but they kept standing in the middle of the panel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for information on the various constraints used by the GridBagLayout.

The `weightx/weighty` constraint controls this behaviour. By default the components will be centered. If you don't want this then you need to have a component with a non-zero constraint.

So in this case you would need to create a dummy component and add it to the end of the panel:

```
JLabel dummy = new JLabel(" ");
gbc.gridy = 4;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
westPanel.add(dummy, gbc);
```

Now all the extra vertical space goes to the last component. The components will still be centered horizontally.

Or, another option is to use a "wrapper" panel:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
wrapper.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(wrapper, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
//add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Now the "westPanel" will be displayed at the top of the BorderLayout.

Or maybe use a BoxLayout with "glue" at the end. Read the tutorial. Each layout manager has its own rules. Understanding the rules allows you to nest panels with different layout mangers to achieve your desired layout.

Nested layouts can simplify the code. For example you could also use a GridLayout on the westPanel and add this panel to the wrapper panel. Then you don't need to worry about the gridx/y constraints.

Comment: I just have one more question: is GridBagLayout so flexible that you can do it on every project? I'm just new to Java Swing; I can't combine much layout yet.
Anyway, thanks, sir, for helping me out with the topic.

Comment: GridBagLayout is flexible, but I still prefer to use multiple layout managers with nested panels. So you need to understand the strengths/weaknesses of all layout managers and choose the appropriate layout manager(s) for the job. As I stated above I would find the GridLayout nested in a BorderLayout the better choice. What happens if after the project is complete someone changes the requirement and states you need to add another button at the top of the panel? Well, with your current logic you would need to modify the "gridy" value of every component. With a GridLayout you just add the button.